# Clarification of Authorization header behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, css, http, https

I am writing authentication mechanism for a practice website. I have managed to create a secure token, but I want it to be sent in  every subsequent request after login so they can be authorized.

I'd ideally like to set it as an Authorization Header, but I do not think the header will be set if a user goes to URL through the browser bar.

How do I get the client to remember to send authorization header every time it visits my domain?

Also I would ideally not like to send the token as a cookie.

**TL;DR:**
I have a few questions about Authorization Header behaviour:

1. Do I need to send Authorization Header in every request, or does the browser do it automatically?
2. If its not automatic, GET requests from user input in the browser bar will never be authenticated since there wont be any JavaScript to attach the Header, How would you solve this issue without using cookies?(page redirection?)
3. If I would need to send Authorization header in every request what would be the best solution?

PS

I am using javascript without any frameworks.

Comment: Which authentication are you using? `Basic`, `Digest`, or `Bearer` of OAuth2.0? I guess it is `Bearer` due to your comment in @Veselin's answer. Just to make sure.

Comment: Currently i havent implemented anything, but i would like to implement Bearer. Also i would like to add i am using vanillaJS, no frameworks

Comment: For `Basic` and `Digest`, the browser will send the `Authorization` header automatically. Please check my answer. Unfortunately, for `Bearer`, I didn't find any interesting description in corresponding RFC.

Answer (score 1):

For `Authorization` header in `Basic` and `Digest` authentication, the answer to your questions are:

*"How do I get the client to remember to send authorization header every time it visits my domain?"*

The client would remember and send authorization header automatically, as long as it conforms to [RFC2617](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt):

> A client SHOULD assume that all paths at or deeper than the depth of
> the last symbolic element in the path field of the Request-URI also
> are within the protection space specified by the Basic realm value of
> the current challenge. A client MAY preemptively send the
> corresponding Authorization header with requests for resources in
> that space without receipt of another challenge from the server. (2 Basic Authentication Scheme)

> ...

> A client should remember the username, password, nonce, nonce count and
> opaque values associated with an authentication session to use to
> construct the Authorization header in future requests within that
> protection space. (3.3 Digest Operation)

*"Do I need to send Authorization Header in every request, or does the browser do it automatically?"*

The browser would do it automatically.

For `Authorization` header in `Bearer` authentication (OAuth 2.0), I searched but didn't find any similar description in [RFC6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750)

Comment: I will do more research into these areas, still not clear how header would be able to get data from local storage "automatically". Does local storage key for access token also have to follow some predefined scheme?

Comment: For `Basic` and `Digest`, you don't need to do anything. It has nothing to do with localStorage. The "automatic" behavior is required by RFC specification.

Comment: "The browser would do it automatically." is clearly not true. Browsers send cookies automatically but not Authorization headers. We have a site where users are unable to access images because the browser does not automatically send the auth header, we have to manually set it on every request.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer your questions.

1. On every request you need to send Authorization Header if you want to auth user. You can find more about Authorization Header at this [link](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/handling-authentication-secrets-in-the-browser)
2. I don't understand this question. If you enter, for example, www.facebook.com in browser bar, you will go on Facebook homepage. If user doesn't have token, show login page, or redirect to www.facebook.com/login. If user have token, go to homepage and in header send token. Facebook store token in cookie, you can store it in Locale storage, for example.
3. What is the best way? On successful login, API gives me token which I save to local storage. Then on every request, I send token. If token is same in database, i got data. If token is not same as token in database, I redirect to login page.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: In your second answer, you said facebook.com will send you to your facebook homepage, if user has token. But the token is sent through Authorization header, Authorization header needs to be set through javascript (header.Set). My question is how is facebook.com recieving token when user visits from browser bar, Thanks in Advance!

Comment: When you for the first time go to www.facebook.com, Facebook will check if you have token in cookie. Then if you have that token, he renders HomeTpl.html. If you don't have token, facebook will render LoginTpl.html. Try to login on facebook and delete your cookies. Facebook will logout you.
The question you are asking is maybe this: What is happening when you type url , www.facebook.com and press search?

Comment: Ok this behaviour is valid for "cookies", and i agree completely. I would like to know how you would be able to manage this with Authorization Header and no cookies? Thanks in advance! (Authorization: Bearer Token)

Comment: You need to store somewhere that token. Check this [link](https://medium.com/@robert.broeckelmann/how-to-submit-your-security-tokens-to-an-api-provider-pt-1-4a68df35843a). Check this [link](https://jwt.io/introduction/) also.